# Plot MNIST digits with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot the MNIST digits using ggplot2.

I tried this but I'm getting the numbers rotated 90 degrees. The code below is to plot the 2nd number in the dataset which corresponds to a 2.

`trainData = read.csv(file = url("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B4Tqe9kUUfrBSllGY29pWmdGQUE"))
    df = expand.grid(y = 0:27, x = 0:27)
    df$col = unlist(trainData[2, -c(1,2)])
    ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = col))`

If possible, please consider in your solution that I plan expand this to plotting a matrix of numbers using `facet_grid` or `facet_wrap`. I want to end with a function that I will pass a vector of rows and the function will get those rows from the dataset and create a matrix of plots (one for each number).

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at `?geom_tile` ...? Wasn't necessarily something you would ahve done even if using the function.  Questions that say "please consider a more general case" that do not then present a dataset with which to illustrate solutions are fundamentally unclear. ( Looks too much like a request to do your machine learning homework for my tastes.)

Comment: Yes, I have look at `?geom_tile` and don't see any argument that would allow me to rotate the matrix that is plotted.

If you see the dataset that I'm providing you'll see that it contains several images, therefore you can illustrate the general solution with this dataset if you want to. (No, this is not for a machine learning homework; I already know how to plot the digits with the base R function (image) but wanted to do it with ggplot2). If you know how to solve the rotation issue please provide some guidance on how to resolve it or the `geom_tile` argument to be used.

Answer (score 1):

`mnist` is a build-in dataset in `keras` package.

Here is one example plot with `ggplot2` and `tidyverse` functions:
To make `geom_tile` work, we need to transform the data a bit.

```
library(keras)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

mnist <- keras::dataset_mnist()

mnist$test$x[sample(1:100,1), 1:28, 1:28] %>%
                as_data_frame() %>% 
                rownames_to_column(var = 'y') %>% 
                gather(x, val, V1:V28) %>%
                mutate(x = str_replace(x, 'V', '')) %>% 
                mutate(x = as.numeric(x),
                       y = as.numeric(y)) %>% 
                mutate(y = 28-y) %>%
                ggplot(aes(x, y))+
                geom_tile(aes(fill = val+1))+
                coord_fixed()+
                theme_void()+
                theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image: Mnist example plot]